# Random number function python that include 1 but not include 0

Tags: python, random

I need to generate a number from 0 to 1 that include 1 but not include 0

The `random.uniform(0,1)` function include 0 but not include 1

How is it possible to do that?

Comment: `[0,1)` is not guaranteed for [`random.uniform`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.uniform). If you devide by `1-random.uniform(0,1)` you could run into a `ZeroDivisionError`.

Answer (score 6):

It can be as simple as `1 - random.uniform(0,1)`

Answer (score 0):

Numpy’s uniform random generator generates values on a [a,b) interval where a is low and b is high.

> Samples are uniformly distributed over the half-open interval [low, high) (includes low, but excludes high). In other words, any value within the given interval is equally likely to be drawn by uniform

[docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively use:

```
import random as r
-r.uniform(-1, 0)
```

So in general:

```
# random number which excludes a but excludes b
import random as r

def my_uniform(a = 0, b = 1):
    return -r.uniform(-b, -a)
```